# Migrating from JSON data to normalized table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Considering a table with bank account related information containing a column for when the entry was created, one for when it was updated and a JSON column with all the bank account related data (a list of bank accounts):

```
Created    Updated     BankAccountData
2020-04-1  2020-04-02  {"Accounts":[{"AccountNumber":"1234","IsValid":true},{"AccountNumber":"4321","IsValid":true}]}
```

I'd like to migrate this into a more normalized version looking something like:

```
Created    Updated    AccountNumber    IsValid
2020-04-01 2020-04-02 1234             true
2020-04-01 2020-04-02 4321             true
```

How would I go about doing that? I've attempted to work with [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples):

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) 
set @json = '{"Accounts": [{"AccountNumber":"1234","IsValid":true},{"AccountNumber":"4321","IsValid":true}]}'

select * 
from openjson(@json)
   with (AccountNumber nvarchar(max) '$.AccountNumber')
```

In this case `AccountNumber` is null. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct [path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (`$.Accounts`) when you call `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema definition. Of course, the correct path expression depends on the JSON structure and can be different.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Created date,    
   Updated date,     
   BankAccountData varchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (Created, Updated, BankAccountData)
VALUES 
   ('20200401','20200402', '{"Accounts":[{"AccountNumber":"1234","IsValid":true},{"AccountNumber":"4321","IsValid":true}]}')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.Created, d.Updated, j.AccountNumber, j.IsValid
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(@json, '$.Accounts') WITH ( 
   AccountNumber varchar(4) '$.AccountNumber',
   IsValid bit '$.IsValid'
) j
```

Result:

```
Created     Updated     AccountNumber   IsValid
2020-04-01  2020-04-02  1234            True
2020-04-01  2020-04-02  4321            True
```